# How to replace facia boards?

Tags: roof, replacement

What are the essential steps to replacing facia boards without destroying the existing shingle roofing?

Answer (score 5):

shirlock homes is correct.  The facia boards should be underneath the drip edge and it will not be affected.  I would go slow removing the facia boards in case the roofer inadvertently nailed the drip edge to the facia.  The steps are simple:

1. Remove facia using a cats paw or similar tool and a hammer.
2. Remove all nails and/or screws that might get in the way of new facia.
3. Replace any of the facia boards behind it that need replaced making sure to end each board on a rafter or truss.
4. Cut facia and nail it up with galvanized nails, (usually 2 every 16"-20") pushing up gently on the shingles and drip edge to move them out of the way.  If you have any angled pieces then a speed square is a must.  How to use one would require a whole nother question and answers.
5. Put a dab of caulk on every nail head and every seam on the facia.
6. Paint.

Comment: Nice detailed procedure. +vote

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the facia boards should be a fairly easy job if the drip edges are not nailed to them. The metal drip edges or shingles should not be nailed to the facia, so they should come off clean without disturbing the shingles.

Comment: Great point, I didn't even think to look for that.